# How can I copy the data in the same cell from daily produced excel files into one origin file

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy

I would really need your support with developing a loop code in VBA that should do the following: Say there is the file X-Date produced daily (e.g. X-20171101,X-20171102 and so on). The information I need is found in the same cell (B287) in the first sheet for each of this kind of files. I would like to have the data inside cell B287 copied into one origin excel file(say Origin.xls). The origin file contains the date in column "A" , and the corresponding number(data inside cell B287) in column "B".

Below, is what I managed to write so far, but it only copies from one file:

Please see below my code so far:

```
Sub eurobig()

Dim Originfile As Workbook
Dim Inputfile As Workbook

Set Inputfile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\YW85SU\..\IX25_20171120.csv")
Set Originfile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\YW85SU\..\Origin.xlsx")

Inputfile.Sheets("IX25_20171120").Range("B287").Copy

Originfile.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").PasteSpecial

Inputfile.Close
```

How can I make it loop through more files?

I would really appreciate your support with this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, there's a way. Write a code. Do you have any we can help you with?

Comment: Yes there is:
`code`
Sub eurobig()
'
Dim Originfile As Workbook
Dim Inputfile As Workbook

'Open both workbooks first:
Set Inputfile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\..\IX25_20171120.csv")
Set Originfile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\..\Origin.xlsx")

'Copy from Input:
Inputfile.Sheets("IX25_20171120").Range("B287").Copy

'Paste to Origin:
Originfile.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").PasteSpecial

'Close Inputfile:
Inputfile.Close
`code`

I am only able to copy from a single file at the moment. I would like to be able to do this in a loop for more files that appear on a daily basis.

Comment: If you want to include code then edit your question and add it there.  Code in comments will typically get skipped.

Comment: @Tim Williams: Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub eurobig()

    Const FPATH As String = "C:\Users\YW85SU\..\"

    Dim Originfile As Workbook
    Dim Inputfile As Workbook, f, c As Range

    Set Originfile = Workbooks.Open(FPATH & "Origin.xlsx")
    Set c = Originfile.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    f = Dir(FPATH & "*.csv")

    Do While Len(f) > 0

        Set Inputfile = Workbooks.Open(FPATH & f)
        c.Value = f
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Inputfile.Sheets(1).Range("B287").Value
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0) 'next row
        Inputfile.Close False
        f = Dir()

    Loop

End Sub
```